# Generic filters and projections

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ be two forcing notions and $\pi:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$  be a projection.

Let $G\subset\mathbb{P}$ and $H\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ the filter generated by $\pi''G$. Define

$$ \mathbb{R} = \left\{p\in \mathbb{P}\ \bigg|\ \pi(p)\in H\right\} $$

then $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $G$ is $M[H]$-generic filter (in $\mathbb{R}$).

This seems rather trivial, but the move into $M[H]$ can add more dense sets making $G$ not generic, this also means that I cant count on $H$ to remain generic in $M[H]$ (else I would just look at $\pi''\left(D\cup(\mathbb{P}\setminus\mathbb{R})\right)$ which will be dense in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: $H$ is never $M[H]$-generic, since $\Bbb Q\setminus H$ is a dense open set in $M[H]$. (Assuming $\Bbb Q$ isn't trivial, that is.)

Comment: Then how to I even talk about genericity in the new model?

Comment: You may have added new dense subsets of $\Bbb P$, but why are there "completely new" dense subsets of $\Bbb R$? You're not trying to be generic for $\Bbb P$, after all.

Comment: What forbids $q\Vdash\dot{D}\subset \dot{\mathbb{R}}$ dense for some $q\in H$?

Comment: That's possible, sure, but you'd still have to meet $G$.

Comment: I still can't figure out why the intersection is not empty. My mind goes to the direction, $\exists p\in G$ s.t $\pi(p)\leq q$ hence $\pi(p)\Vdash \dot{D}\subset \dot{\mathbb {R}}$ is dense.  Somehow getting to $\pi(p) \Vdash \check{p} \in \dot{D}$